# EIP-155 Error when trying to deploy contract to Polygon from Brownie

Tags: deployment, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to deploy my contract to Matic/Polygon main net and am running into the error "only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC". This is my network settings [Network Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io7dz.png) . Same contract deploys perfect to Ethereum Rinkeby test net so I know it's not a contractual error. I have tried all the public matic RPC's and all result in the same error and I can not seem to find any info online about using Brownie to deploy to Polygon other than that is EIP-155 has to do with the deployment of the same code to multiple chains at once. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes to this problem as well, I ended up solving it by uninstalling all brownie related files and re-installing and that did the trick for me. Hopefully that helps y'all.

Comment: Nice, it's likely that you were using an outdated version of brownie